# PHP redirect conditional statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to modify the ID login system to work for admin and users but it dosnt work, any suggestions? Why wont my access level MySQL query not work please help. There is also a connection to the db and call to functions but these are nothing to do with it I need to make it work with this single form.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/connections/db.php');
include('lib/functions/functions.php');
If acces_level = 2 {
$returnURL = "users/index.php";
   } else {
If access_level = 1 {
   $returnURL = "secdirpostdata//aderr/auth/admin/index.php";

//For login

    // we check if everything is filled in and perform checks

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
    {
        die(msg(0,"Username and / or password fields empty!"));
    }

    else
        {
            $res = login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
                if ($res == 1){
                    die(msg(0,"Incorrect Username or Password"));
                }
                if ($res == 2){
                    die(msg(0,"Your account has been suspended, contact us to remove the suspension"));
                }
                if ($res == 3){
                    die(msg(0,"Your account has not been activated. Please check your email's inbox or spam folder for a link to activate your account. If you are having problems activating your account then contact us to resolve the issue."));
                }
                if ($res == 4){
                    die(msg(0,"Your account has been disconnected and is banned from using server, Contact Us to resolve this issue."));
                }
                if ($res == 99){
                    echo(msg(1,$returnURL));
                }
        }

    function msg($status,$txt)
    {
        return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for `if` and `else if` are wrong. Additionally your `=` check is an assignment when it should be `==`. And when you have `acces_level == 2` and `acces_level == 1` those should be a variable so it should be `$acces_level == 2` and `$acces_level == 1`. Finally, you need parenthesis around the conditions. Examples below.

Where you have this:

```
If acces_level = 2 {
$returnURL = "users/index.php";
   } else {
If access_level = 1 {
   $returnURL = "secdirpostdata//aderr/auth/admin/index.php";
```

It should be this:

```
if ($access_level == 2) {
  $returnURL = "users/index.php";
}
elseif ($access_level == 1) {
  $returnURL = "secdirpostdata//aderr/auth/admin/index.php";
```

Also, it is unclear if the variable is `acces_level` or `access_level` with two `s`’s.  In general you need to provide more details. But your formatting is way off to say the least.

Comment: I'm starting to think that your answer makes more sense. It's really hard to know though, exactly why the OP set it up the way it is now, since there are other conditional statements elsewhere, resembling what you put in. I might end up deleting my answer, if I can't see the whole picture.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you and Jake please look at this script to see how I can implement this feature please http://www.venturehapa.biz/umscript/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't go through all those files. @user3132932 You took this from a demo, and I for one won't go through all of it. If Jake wants to do it, then that's up to him. I've done what I could with your initial question while pointing out the errors.

Comment: also the link is a link to the coding im using

Comment: The only thing I could tell is that the DB is using `level_access` and not `access_level` inside `functions.php` file. @user3132932

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an assignment with the equal sign `=`

```
If access_level = 1 {
If acces_level = 2 {
```

Instead of checking if it's equal to `==`

Replace them both with:

```
If access_level == 1
If acces_level == 2 {
```

that's checking if it's equal to.

### Edit

Considering what Jake put in for his answer, using the following would also make more sense.

(Credit to Jake Gould)

```
If $access_level == 1 {
If $acces_level == 2 {
```

**N.B.** You have `acces_level` with a (possible) missing `s` where as you have it correctly spelled in `access_level = 1` do double-check everything. There is no other reference to `access_level` or `acces_level` or any other variable in your posted code.

Comment: Its querying a table in users where level access but im confuesed could you post the code, please and thanks &  MERRY CHRISTMAS

Comment: What does your DB code look like? @user3132932 It's not in your question.

Comment: My database has 5 tables and within the table users their is a collum called access_level this will give access to users meaning admins users will be give level 1 access where as users will be given level 2 access

Comment: You may be confusing the condition with a variable. What is the relation to `acces_level`? You may want to do something to the affect of `If $acces_level == 2` @user3132932 Depending on what that is related to and how you're bringing it into the whole picture.

Comment: I just tryed the code and it isnt working mabey Im not selecting the proper table etc. Please check out this script for the code im using...

Comment: Which script is that, I don't see a link. @user3132932 you may not have enough rep points to post links in comments. Please add your full code to your question.

Comment: Plus as I stated in my **EDIT**, you may have mispelled the word `acces_level` with a missing `s` which should read as `access_level` and possibly a `$` in front of it to make it as a variable. I.e.: `$access_level` @user3132932 that I need to know how it is being taken from, if it's coming from another file.

Comment: Yep, I had that impression just as soon as I saw the OP's first comment; another can of worms. @JakeGould

Answer (score -1):

Also keep the format correct

```
if (acces_level == 2) {
```

not

```
If acces_level = 2 {
```

just better formatting doesnt mean you actually need the ()

Comment: I'm sorry its just what I could easily make out. Im not a pro just try to help with the little that I can.